# Include File - session error

Tags: php, session, header, include, comments

For a small comments widget.
I'm trying to **include** that widget into any .php file at wish- in the most practical way for the user with just:

```
<?php include "comments.php"; ?>
```

I'm trying to create an **admin-login-panel** right into the widget, to offer the logged admin to delete the posts (and more other options).

**The problem is**: i have now to start to use the `$_SESSION`, to prevent the admin having to login over and over again at each change / page-refresh.
But, using sessions inside the widget I can only see header and session WARNINGS `...olready started...` ....and so on.

Is NOT an option to force the user to put into his pages top 'session_starts', I'd like to keep things simple. Just php-`include` the widget.

Can I still keep trying with php sessions or should I try something else?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: if you're getting a `session already started` error, it means that you're probably starting the session in more than one place.

Comment: no, it was my first session in the whole project. It's a response that is commonly browsable on any PHPsite. But there's more: ob_start() before session_start() suggestions and even more advanced/complicated things. At least for the end-user. I still believe there's a easyer, banal solution.

Comment: SOLVED. (flat-file.) Well this was almost impossible to achieve using SESSION. Not in a widget style. I created a temp.php file that grabs the visitor IP. If the user tries to login entering the right 'username' and 'pass' that IP is immediately written into the temp.php file. So next time the user (admin) tried to login, or at page-reload the panel was there waiting for him. Unless 'logout' was clicked. Now, as the widget refreshes at comments delete, i just made a jQuery cookie to tell the admin panel to stay always OPEN, once clicked. Unless 'logout' was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, with what information you have given us, this is what your problem is: PHP Sessions uses a special cookie that is sent in a header. So you must perform a session_start(); before any other content it sent to the browser, so it can set the cookie in the header. So unfortunately, it looks like you will have to start a session outside of their including of a widget.

Why is starting the session outside of the widget not an option? Do you not have control over the other PHP pages?

Comment: The idea is a 'standalone' comments widget. The idea is to keep things simple. And the simplest thing for a final user is to copy the widget to the server (root or posts/blog folder) and afterwards, any time, just paste the include script into the files after any post.

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to configure your site to auto-start the session on each page.

You can typically accomplish this by modifying a PHP configuration value for the directory via a .htaccess file like so:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag session.auto_start on
</IfModule>
```

Also I would recommend referrencing the root path of your website in the include, so you can use that comment include statement on any page without having to add a bunch of '../../../' to the path.

```
<?php 
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/header.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion Jason. As I'm new (a week) in PHP, I'll make more researches about that solution. I will make you know about the results! THANKS A LOT FOR THE SUGGESTIONS TO ALL !

Comment: Jason, i'd like at the end to leave the client site untouched and unchanged. Just 2 rules. Upload the package to the server - and include comment system wherever they want. Still searching for an answer... thanks